# Union and Merging different tables together at the same time

Tags: merge, duplicates

I have 12 different tables with primary keys. I want to merge the values corresponding to those primary keys in all my 12 different tables and remove the duplicates, as some primary keys are repeating in different tables.

In the end I want to append all 12 tables in one.

I am working on SQL ( Microsoft SQL Server)

Comment: First of all, what language are you working with here?

Comment: I am working with SQL on Miscrosft SQL Server Management Studio 2012